# Django: Testing Post View

Tags: python, django, file, testing, post

I'm trying to test my post with a testing suite. I've just been trying to follow the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post) to do this.  The main problem I'm having right now is that response.context is returning None.
This is what my test class looks like:

```
class JSONHandlerTester(TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()
    self.jsonTestPath = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,'json','jsonTests')


def testing(self):
    for test in os.listdir(self.jsonTestPath):
        testFile = os.path.join(os.path.join(self.jsonTestPath),test)
        split = test.split('.')
        testName = split[0]
        testNameArray = re.findall('[a-zA-z][^A-Z]*', testName)
        project = testNameArray[0]
        team = testNameArray[1]
        with open(testFile) as json:
            response = self.client.post('/JSONChecker', {'json_project': project, 'json_team': team, 'json': json})
        print response
        print response.context
        if (response.context['title'] == "Congratulations!!! Your JSON Passes!!!" and testNameArray[2] == "Pass") or (response.context['title'][2:] == "The" and testNameArray[2] == "Fail"):
           print test+': Works'
        else:
           print test+': BREAKS: PROBLEM DETECTED'
```

Also this is what my render looks like:

```
return render(request, 'JSONChecker.html',context = {'title': title, 'validationErrors':validationErrors,'errors':errors, 'isLoggedIn':isLoggedIn, 'form': form, 'post':post})
```

If the form is invalid or the extension isn't json this is what the render looks like (this shouldn't be triggered by suite):

```
return render(
            request,
            'JSONChecker.html',
            context = {'title': title,'errors': errors,'isLoggedIn':isLoggedIn,'team':team, 'email':email,'form':form, 'post': post},
        )
```

Content-Length: 0

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Location: /JSONChecker/

I'm using Django 1.11 and Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Context attribute is only populated when using the DjangoTemplates backend.

Comment: Do I have to pull the context from the backend? I tried using context_data but I got an error that said that it didn't exist.  How would I be able to populate the context attribute so I can pull the variable that I want to pull?